# Remove Rspec testing data after testing using database_cleaner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, state, database-cleaner

I am using Rspec to test my rails application. This application uses some preloaded data and some customized data. now i want to test this application in the same development environment without changing the state of the database.
I use the database_cleaner gem to remove data after testing. but it removes all the data in the tables. Any suggesting will be helpful, how can i testing the code without changing the data in the database.

Comment: This problem is similar but the solution was not. But the  remaining question is how can i remove some instance of data from database not the whole using database_cleaner. e.g Remove only testing rows created during testing from the table.

Comment: I agree, this is not an exact duplicate.  I'm voting to leave open.